# Find Woocommerce Currency Id

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How to find the selected currency id in woo-commerce.I want this id to show on my WordPress page.Is there is any function in woo-commerce through which i can find the id.

Answer (score 1):

woocommerce store his currency in wp_options table.

```
SELECT *
   FROM `wp_options`
   WHERE `option_name` = 'woocommerce_currency'
```

this will show you the currency symbol like `USD`, you can get it with `get_option('woocommerce_currency')`. I am sure that is what you want.

OR

take a look on this documentation http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/function-get_woocommerce_currencies.html